# How do you navigate/configure navigation from complex type to entity type in OData in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

The title basically says my question, say I have classes like these

```cs
public class ContrivedComplexClass
{
    public string stringy { get; set; }
    public ContrivedEntityClass ContrivedEntityClass { get; set; }
}

public class ContrivedEntityClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int inty { get; set; }
}
```

my controller action is like this

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GetContrivedComplexClass()")]
public async virtual Task<ContrivedComplexClass> GetContrivedComplexClass()
{
     await Task.Delay(10);
     ContrivedComplexClass contrivedComplexClass = new ContrivedComplexClass() { stringy = "asdf", ContrivedEntityClass = new ContrivedEntityClass() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), inty = 3 } };
     return contrivedComplexClass;
}
```

and my edm model is configured like so

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
builder.EntitySet<ContrivedEntityClass>("ContrivedEntityClass").EntityType.HasKey(f => f.Id);
builder.Function("GetContrivedComplexClass").Returns<ContrivedComplexClass>();
```

when I call the function from a browser or postman or whatever with the URL

```
https://localhost:5001/odata/GetContrivedComplexClass()?Expand=ContrivedEntityClass
```

it only returns the properties on the complex type like

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#WebPortal.ContrivedComplexClass","stringy":"asdf"}
```

Anybody have any idea how I should be querying or configuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your EDM model as:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{​​​​
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<ContrivedEntityClass>("ContrivedEntityClass").EntityType.HasKey(f => f.Id); ;
    var function = builder.Function("GetContrivedComplexClass");
    function.ReturnsFromEntitySet<ContrivedComplexClass>("GetContrivedComplexClass");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}​​​​
```

Add a key to ContrivedComplexClass:

```
public class ContrivedComplexClass
{​​​​
    [Key]
    public int Id {​​​​ get; set; }​​​​
    public string stringy {​​​​ get; set; }​​​​
    public ContrivedEntityClass ContrivedEntityClass {​​​​ get; set; }​​​​
}​​​​



public class ContrivedEntityClass
{​​​​
    public Guid Id {​​​​ get; set; }​​​​
    public int inty {​​​​ get; set; }​​​​
}​​​​
```

Awith the URL:

```
https://localhost:5001/odata/GetContrivedComplexClass()?$Expand=ContrivedEntityClass
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GetContrivedComplexClass()")]
public async virtual Task<ContrivedComplexClass> GetContrivedComplexClass()
{​​​​
    await Task.Delay(3);
    ContrivedComplexClass contrivedComplexClass = new ContrivedComplexClass
    {​​​​
        Id = 1,
        stringy = "asdf",
        ContrivedEntityClass = new ContrivedEntityClass()
        {​​​​
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            inty = 3
        }​​​​
    }​​​​;
    return contrivedComplexClass;
}​​​​
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about trying to add the Id on the the complex type, but wouldn't have thought of the return from collection part.